# CodeDom can't find WindowsBase.dll

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm trying to follow MSDN's [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) on using `CodeDom` and the `CompilerParameters` class. For another project I'm working on, I need to reference WindowsBase so I'm just testing using this example. I add a reference to `WindowsBase.dll` and `System.dll` via the following code:

```
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("WindowsBase.dll");
```

However, when I compile it I get the error `CS0006: Metadata file 'WindowsBase.dll' could not be found`.

Why does it work for System.dll but not WindowsBase.dll?

I've searched elsewhere online and they suggested that the problem was with GAC. I'm not too familiar with GAC but I've checked the following directories,

```
C:\Windows\assembly
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35
```

and I can see that WindowBase.dll is there. If I add the assembly via the full path, `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll` then it works but I would prefer not to do that because then it wouldn't be scalable. Is there a way I can add the reference using just the name? Or at least get the full path dynamically?

Comment: What framework version are you targeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is meant as a workaround.  If another non-workaround answer presents itself, I encourage you to use that one over this one.

You can get the absolute path of `WindowsBase.dll` by referencing a class from that assembly and getting the assembly location.  For example:

```
typeof(System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher).Assembly.Location
```

Pick any class you wish from that assembly.

By doing this you will get the full path of WindowsBase.dll without hardcoding that path into your code.